# Async slave node missing WAL files on Postgres11

Tags: postgresql, master-slave, postgresql-11, wal

I have 3 VM nodes running Master-Slave Postgres-11. They are being managed by Pacemaker.

```
Node Attributes:
* Node node04:
    + master-pgsqlins                   : 1000
    + pgsqlins-data-status              : LATEST
    + pgsqlins-master-baseline          : 000000C0D8000098
    + pgsqlins-status                   : PRI
* Node node05:
    + master-pgsqlins                   : -INFINITY
    + pgsqlins-data-status              : STREAMING|ASYNC
    + pgsqlins-status                   : HS:async
* Node node06:
    + master-pgsqlins                   : 100
    + pgsqlins-data-status              : STREAMING|SYNC
    + pgsqlins-status                   : HS:sync
```

`Async node` throws an error at times that the required WAL file is missing. It then stops the replication and starts it again.

On the `master` node, WAL archiving is enabled and they are synced to another folder named `wal_archive`. There is another process that keeps removing the files from that `wal_archive` folder. So I understand why the slave node would throw that error, but what I want to understand is that **how is it able to start back again without that missing file**?

The **postgresql.conf**

```
# Connection settings
# -------------------
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 600

tcp_keepalives_idle = 0
tcp_keepalives_interval = 0
tcp_keepalives_count = 0

# Memory-related settings
# -----------------------
shared_buffers = 2GB           # Physical memory 1/4
##DEBUG:  mmap(1652555776) with MAP_HUGETLB failed, huge pages disabled: Cannot allocate memory
#huge_pages = try              # on, off, or try
#temp_buffers = 16MB            # depends on DB checklist
work_mem = 8MB                 # Need tuning
effective_cache_size = 4GB      # Physical memory 1/2
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
wal_buffers = 64MB

# WAL/Replication/HA   settings
# --------------------
wal_level = logical
synchronous_commit = remote_write
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p /xxxxx/wal_archive/%f'
#archive_command = ':'
max_wal_senders=5
hot_standby = on
restart_after_crash = off
wal_sender_timeout = 60000
wal_receiver_status_interval = 2
max_standby_streaming_delay = -1
max_standby_archive_delay = -1
hot_standby_feedback = on
random_page_cost = 1.5

max_wal_size = 5GB
min_wal_size = 200MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
checkpoint_timeout = 30min

# Logging settings
# ----------------
log_destination = 'csvlog,syslog'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_filename = 'postgresql_%Y%m%d.log'
log_truncate_on_rotation = off
log_rotation_age = 1h
log_rotation_size = 0

log_timezone = 'Japan'
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: [%l-1] %h:%u@%d:[XXXPG]:CODE:%e '

log_statement = ddl
log_min_messages = info         # DEBUG5
log_min_error_statement = info  # DEBUG5
log_error_verbosity = default
log_checkpoints = on
log_lock_waits = on
log_temp_files = 0
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_duration = off
log_min_duration_statement = 1000
log_autovacuum_min_duration = 3000ms

track_functions = pl
track_activity_query_size = 8192

# Locale/display settings
# -----------------------
lc_messages = 'C'
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'  # ja_JP.eucJP
lc_numeric  = 'en_US.UTF-8'  # ja_JP.eucJP
lc_time     = 'en_US.UTF-8'  # ja_JP.eucJP
timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo'
bytea_output = 'escape'


# Auto vacuum settings
# -----------------------
autovacuum = on
autovacuum_max_workers = 3
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 200
#shared_preload_libraries  = 'pg_stat_statements,auto_explain'   <------------------check this

auto_explain.log_min_duration = 10000
auto_explain.log_analyze = on
include '/var/lib/pgsql/tmp/rep_mode.conf' # added by pgsql RA
```

On the async slave node, this is the **recovery.conf**

```
primary_conninfo = 'host=1xx.xx.xx.xx port=5432 user=replica application_name=node05 keepalives_idle=60 keepalives_interval=5 keepalives_count=5'
restore_command = 'rsync -a /xxxxx/wal_archive/%f %p'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
standby_mode = 'on'
```

The **logs** about the error from master

```
2021-07-05 23:35:02.321 JST,,,28926,,60e16b42.70fe,122,,2021-07-04 17:03:14 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"checkpoint complete: wrote 2897 buffers (1.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed
, 2 recycled; write=106.770 s, sync=0.050 s, total=106.827 s; sync files=251, longest=0.017 s, average=0.001 s; distance=20262 kB, estimate=46658 kB",,,,,,,,,""
2021-07-05 23:35:02.322 JST,,,28926,,60e16b42.70fe,123,,2021-07-04 17:03:14 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"checkpoint starting: immediate force wait",,,,,,,,,""
2021-07-05 23:35:02.347 JST,,,28926,,60e16b42.70fe,124,,2021-07-04 17:03:14 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"checkpoint complete: wrote 173 buffers (0.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed,
 1 recycled; write=0.007 s, sync=0.012 s, total=0.026 s; sync files=43, longest=0.005 s, average=0.001 s; distance=14410 kB, estimate=43434 kB",,,,,,,,,""
2021-07-05 23:35:02.348 JST,"replica","",3451,"1xx.xx.xx.xxx:45120",60e16bfc.d7b,3,"streaming C1/97C3E000",2021-07-04 17:06:20 JST,116/0,0,ERROR,XX000,"requested WAL segment 00000001000000C100000097 has already been removed",,,,,,,,,"node05"
2021-07-05 23:35:02.361 JST,"replica","",3451,"1xx.xx.xx.xxx:45120",60e16bfc.d7b,4,"idle",2021-07-04 17:06:20 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"disconnection: session time: 30:28:41.550 user=replica database= host=172.17.48.141 port=45120",,,,,,,,,"node05"
2021-07-05 23:35:02.399 JST,,,24896,"1xx.xx.xx.xxx:49278",60e31896.6140,1,"",2021-07-05 23:35:02 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"connection received: host=1xx.xx.xx.xxx port=49278",,,,,,,,,""
2021-07-05 23:35:02.401 JST,"postgres","postgres",24851,"[local]",60e31896.6113,3,"idle",2021-07-05 23:35:02 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.251 user=postgres database=postgres host=[local]",,,,,,,,,"postgres@node04"
2021-07-05 23:35:02.403 JST,"replica","",24896,"1xx.xx.xx.xxx:49278",60e31896.6140,2,"authentication",2021-07-05 23:35:02 JST,116/72,0,LOG,00000,"replication connection authorized: user=replica",,,,,,,,,""
```

The **logs** about the error from async slave node

```
2021-07-05 23:35:02.359 JST,,,2541,,60e16bfc.9ed,2,,2021-07-04 17:06:20 JST,,0,FATAL,XX000,"could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000000C100000097 has already been removed",,,,,,,,,""
2021-07-05 23:35:02.408 JST,,,4703,,60e31896.125f,1,,2021-07-05 23:35:02 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"started streaming WAL from primary at C1/98000000 on timeline 1",,,,,,,,,""
2021-07-05 23:35:03.318 JST,,,4835,"[local]",60e31897.12e3,1,"",2021-07-05 23:35:03 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"connection received: host=[local]",,,,,,,,,""
```

`Sync slave node` doesn't throw this error, only `async slave node`, and that too recovers without any manual intervention. Is there a way to avoid this error other than by not removing the archived wal files from the `wal_archive` folder every 2 mins?

Comment: There may be a slave lag on the async slave node. `wal_keep_segments` should be set high enough to allow a slave to catch up after a reasonable lag. `archive_mode` enables WAL archiving which can be used to recover files older than `wal_keep_segments provides.`

Comment: My question was how the async slave node was able to catchup despite missing the particular WAL file?

Comment: In a production environment, it is always advisable to have the parameter restore_command set appropriately. This parameter takes a shell command (or a script) that can be used to fetch the WAL needed by a slave if the WAL is not available on the master.

Comment: I am sorry but that doesn't answer my question. The `restore_command` is already set. Please read the question again.

Comment: step 6 will explain the answer if WAL logs got archived what happens
https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/09/07/setting-up-streaming-replication-postgresql/

Comment: `restore_command` helps the slave get the appropriate WALs from the archive location.

Comment: The `restore_command` is properly set in my case and if that is helping async slave node to recover, then, why do we even get that error that the requested WAL segment has already been removed? It should look at the archive folder and not throw this error.

Comment: First, it checks in **pg_xlog** or **pg_wal* location if not found then through exception and start restoring. To mitigate this exception set **wal_keep_segments** higher.

Comment: So are you saying that this is a usual behavior? Before retrieving files from the archive folder, this error would be thrown and then the files will be restored?